# Drawing Random Coloured Circles on html Canvas with js?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm just starting with js and need little help! I got these two functions, to draw circles and splattered circles, I need to create a **for loop** to draw 10 random coloured circles and 10 random splattered circles! how can i do it? thanks

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="550" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
    var randomColour;
    var randomSize;
    var xPos;
    var yPos;
    var i;
    var j;

    randomColour = '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substring(4); // random colour
    c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    function drawFilledCircle(size,xPos,Ypos,colour){    //draw circle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(xPos,yPos,size,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = colour;
        ctx.fill();
    }

    function drawSplatter(size,xPos,yPos,colour){       // draw splattered circle
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            var splatSize = size / Math.round(Math.random()*30);
            drawFilledCircle(splatSize,xPos + Math.round(Math.random()*50),yPos + Math.round(Math.random()*50),colour);
        }
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Please specify what exactly you want to know. What are you seeing? How is it different from what you want to see? What solutions have you tried?

Comment: You have two functions, one for paint filled circle and other to draw splatter circle. So call both functions with the correct arguments when you need / like. Good luck

Comment: I would like to know what the "for loop" would look like to generate those random circles using these functions and random colour, so when the page is refreshed it generates 10 normal and 10 splattered circles. I am really new to js, :) thanks

Comment: I have this code that can be used to generate one normal and one splattered circle, but how do I use it in a "for loop" to generate 10 each?             randomColour = '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substring(2, 8);
randomSize = Math.round(Math.random()*50);
xPos = Math.round(Math.random()*550);
yPos = Math.round(Math.random()*400);
drawFilledCircle(randomSize, xPos, yPos, randomColour);
drawSplatter(randomSize, xPos, yPos, randomColour);

Comment: The `Ypos` in `drawFilledCircle` needs to be changed to `yPos`.  Also the random color wasn't working for me so that needs to be changed as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var randomColour;
var randomSize;
var xPos;
var yPos;
var i;
var j;

c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function drawFilledCircle(size, xPos, yPos, colour) { //draw circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = colour;
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawSplatter(size, xPos, yPos, colour) { // draw splattered circle
  for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    var splatSize = size / Math.round(Math.random() * 30);
    drawFilledCircle(splatSize, xPos + Math.round(Math.random() * 50), yPos + Math.round(Math.random() * 50), colour);
  }
}

var maxSize = 30;
var minSize = 10;
var maxX = c.width;
var maxY = c.height;

function randoms() {
  var size = Math.ceil(Math.random() * maxSize);
  size = Math.max(size, minSize);
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxX);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxY);
  var colour = '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2,6);
  return {size:size, x:x, y:y, colour:colour};
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var r = randoms();
  drawFilledCircle(r.size, r.x, r.y, r.colour);
  r = randoms();
  drawSplatter(r.size, r.x, r.y, r.colour);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#222222;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="550" height="400"></canvas>
```